# Dart round a figure but as a double

Tags: flutter, dart, double

I want to multiply a figure and then have it rounded to remove any decimal places but returned as a double, rather than an int since that is what I need.

I've tried this:

```
double number = 84.5;

double coke = (number * 2.3).round()) as double;
```

and this:

```
double coke = double.parse(number * 2.3).round());
```

But I can't get it to be a double, it just throws errors. The value would be `194.35` in this case and I want it to be `194.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double number = 84.5;
double answer = (number * 2.3).roundToDouble(); // 194.0
```

Comment: Wow I did not know about that. Works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[CopsOnRoad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57449337/179715) is the most direct way, but in general the way to convert an `int` to a `double` is to use [`int.toDouble`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/num/toDouble.html):

```dart
double number = 84.5;

double coke = (number * 2.3).round().toDouble();
```

Using `as double` doesn't work because `as` changes what type the object is *treated* as but doesn't change the underlying object.